# Disjoint union for monotonicity

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Show that if $A\subset B$, then $\mu(A) \le \mu(B)$.

Proof

[image]

[Wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union)

[image]

I don't see how that "disjoint union" works here. Is this the wrong definition of "disjoint union", or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the monotonicity property, the author has made use of the finite additivity property and the fact that measures are non-negative.

More precisely, given a collection of pairwise disjoint sets $A_{k}\in\mathcal{F}$, where $1\leq k\leq n$, one has that
\begin{align*}
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(A_{k})
\end{align*}

At your case, one has that $A_{1} = A$ and $A_{2} = B\cap A^{c}$. Consequently, given that $A\subseteq B$, one has that
\begin{align*}
\mu(B) = \mu(A\cup(B\cap A^{c})) = \mu(A) + \mu(B\cap A^{c}) \geq \mu(A)
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

They just mean a **union** of two **disjoint** (i.e. with empty intersection) sets. Ignore the definition in Wikipedia for this case.